# Is there a way to work on firefox with selenium 3.4?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to work on Firefox with selenium 3.4 as

I am always getting error as below:-

> "FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739392/webdriver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-firefoxdriver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-typ)

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver will support the latest firefox also. but you have to set the properties for that

download "geckodriver.exe" file and download the file from below URL :-

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\SeleniumAutomation\\geckodriver-v0.9.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Update your firefox and selenium server and client-combined jar

Comment: Thanks Shubham for the reply,  I set the properties as shown
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

But it is still not working

Comment: Have you updated the selenium jars and Firefox browser

Comment: Firefox is updated, But please advise about How to update the selenium jars.

I got error : Firefox can't be resolved to a type

Comment: Selenium Standalone Server and Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings

Comment: check this out also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739392/webdriver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-firefoxdriver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-typ