# WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type for Eclipse oxygen with Selenium 3.8.1 in Windows 10

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

There is an existing question for the same problem but that question was not completely answered, so posting new question.

I am new to selenium and trying to execute the very basic script, but getting the compilation errors. I am using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2 and Selenium 3.8.1. I have added all the necessary Jar files and used the Geckodriver as well, still i am getting errors. Below are the error messages in the console window:

**"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

```js
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.setProperty("Webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\vermap6\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
  // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    
          //Launch the Online Store Website
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   
          // Print a Log In message to the screen
          System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.google.com");
   
    //Wait for 5 Sec
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
          // Close the driver
          driver.quit();
  
 }

}
```

```
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type

FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type"**
```

Can anybody tell me what mistake i am doing ? Attaching screenshots.    [Webdriver Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6L97.png) [JAr Files in Selenium 3.8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAqTo.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of text. It is hard to search and harder to copy-paste.

Comment: You say you added all necessary jars, but from the image I do not see selenium.jar.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SiKing I have added a sceenshot of jar files available in selenium 3.8.1 and i have added a code snippet as well. Could you please have a look and comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739392/webdriver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-firefoxdriver-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-typ)

Comment: Did you include the client-combined-3.8.1.jar in your project?

Comment: @SiKing Yes, Both "client-combined-3.81.jar" and "client-combined-3.81-sources.jar" were included in the project.

Comment: Refresh your project [F5], clean, and rebuild. I do not know what else to say. I use Maven to figure all this stuff for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about file permission. I guess you are using Mac or Linux and the default permission of the library doesn't allow Eclipse to read it. What you need is going to the directory in `Terminal` and then use `sudo chmod` to change the permission.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ./
```

Then you may need to restart Eclipse.

Comment: @Bauban I am on Windows 10. Any troubleshoot can you suggest for Windows 10 if applicable

Comment: @Prabhat Can you check permission of the files and folder? Go to the folder or file > Right Click > Property > Security. Then make sure that your username has the right to access them.